# Best practice: Access properties

Tags: ios, objective-c

Searching the internet there appears to be a large discussion regarding how to access properties the best way. Some seem to prefer the dot-notation, and some seems to be utterly disgusted by the use of dots. As a newbie to Objective-C and cocoa I would really appreciate if someone could tell me which of the following that should be considered "best practice" in your experience.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;
@end
```

Which of the following should be considered best practise accessing e.g. "hidden" - property of the UILabel?

**1**

```
self.myLabel.hidden = YES;
```

**2**

```
[self.myLabel setHidden:YES];
```

**3**

```
[[self myLabel] setHidden:YES];
```

**4**

```
[self myLabel].hidden = YES;
```

**5**

All of the above but with the auto-synthesized `_myLabel`

Sorry if this is a very subjective question but would really like to have your input!

**TO SUMMARIZE:**

All are "best practice". Choose the one you think to be the prettiest line of code and stick with it.

Comment: I would say there all best practice. It is really what is best for you. I prefer to use number 3 as I just find it easier to read

Comment: I usually use #2, but hey, that's my problem :)

Comment: They all work, and they all call the same method. Just the syntax is different, so it's an aesthetic matter and I think that your question is superflous.

Comment: @Filip you forgot _myLabel.hidden = YES;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone is curious: 1-4 all do the same thing. Specifically, they use the getter and setter. 5 is direct access -- it does not use the getter/setter.

My recommendation is to accept that dot notation is messaging and messaging is almost always how you interact with your object, so just go with dot notation.

Selector matching can be stronger with dot notation:

```
// ARC
NSURL * url = nil;

NSObject<NSFilePresenter>* presenter = nil;
url = [presenter presentedItemURL]; // << match
url = presenter.presentedItemURL; // << property matched to presenter's method

NSObject * object = nil;
url = object.presentedItemURL; // << ERROR object/selector mismatch
url = [object presentedItemURL]; // << ERROR object/selector mismatch

id untyped = nil;
url = untyped.presentedItemURL; // << ERROR object/selector mismatch (Good compiler)
url = [untyped presentedItemURL]; // << OOPS, vague selector matched
```

So the increased type safety you introduce by using dot notation can save you in maintenance as well as future errors.

You're not likely to confuse it for member access, unless you think you are dealing with a struct (or C++ class), and there are numerous compiler checks to warn you of direct ivar access.

Direct access (e.g. `_myLabel.prop` and `self->_myLabel.prop`) should be avoided (barring a few edge cases). The exception to this rule is in partially initialized states -- in your initializers and `-dealloc`, you should use direct access, and you should not use the accessor methods.

Of course, there are other places where it reads nicely:

```
return array.count; <<< OK - clear, although not strictly a @property
```

...and you can take it too far:

```
NSString * string = NSString.alloc.init; <<< GROSS! you will not make friends using this
```

Comment: But we can't use argumented nested call for `NSString * string = [NSString.alloc initWithFormat:@"string"];` So you use . when you dont have arguments and [] when you have arguments

Comment: @AnoopVaidya my point is that `NSString.alloc.init` is a BAD way to use dot syntax. `NSString * string = [[NSString alloc] init];` should be used instead.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using this notation `[self.myLabel setHidden:YES];` just to make clear in my code that I'm setting a value for something.

There's really not a big difference between them in terms of performance. It's up to you

Comment: Yeah, I've been using this notation too but then I though since 'myLabel' is really a property to I though that [[self myLabel] setHidden:YES]; would be to code more consequent...

Comment: There's really no big difference as I said! But I read somewhere, I don't remember where, that Apple encourages the use of [] notation.

Comment: With the new feature auto synthesize from Xcode, I would write like this now: `[_myLabel setHidden:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

What I've seen is using dot notation for properties, so you'd use

```
self.myLabel.hidden = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

> All are good practices.
>
> But **best practice** depends on your choice .

Although you forgot mention one more in your list.

> **_myLabel.hidden = YES;**